# Dynamically change style for iterated list

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, aura-iteration

Wanna add some color gradation(if its possible without js calling) for my iterated elements, but got some trouble with calling index value inside style param. Code look like this:

```
<aura:iteration items={!v.list} var="element" indexVar="index">
     <div style="background-color: rgb(255-index*10, ...)">{!element.Name}</div>
</aura:iteration>
```

Will appreciate any suggestion/recommendation

Comment: Can you elaborate what [specific issue](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) you are facing?

Comment: its doesn't work with my  `<div style="{!'background-color: rgb(' + 255-index*20 + ','  + 255-index*20 +  ','  + 255-index*20 +  ')'}"` and I'm not sure is it possible to work like this